# crystal report issue while opening

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

[2nd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cCzG.jpg)

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUzgz.jpg)

i am facing error while opening crystal report . i am using ms sql backend

```
     Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.Enabled = True
    Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = "E:\vb.n et\Delltech Erp System Updated 11-05-2019\Delltech Inventory System\Delltech Inventory System\cpv.rpt"
    Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "(cashpayment.CashPaymentid)=" + CashPaymentidTextBox.Text.ToString

    Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    Form5.Show()
```

is there any way to view report by ID? like if user save cashpayment voucher , on save he can able to view and print the saved voucher . i tried above code but it throwing error 
picture attached

Comment: Shouldn't you be using curly braces instead of parenthèses? `{cashpayment.CashPaymentid}`.

Comment: yeah sorry for that but still same error is coming with new line

"A string is required here"

check image attached name 2nd error